# Diferença entre Console.Read(); e Console.ReadLine();

Tags: c#, .net, console

Estou começando a aprender C# e fiquei um pouco confuso com uma coisa.

Qual é a real diferença entre `Console.Read();` e `Console.ReadLine();` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825943/difference-between-console-read-and-console-readline

Comment: Vê a documentação: [`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @dcastro Obrigado pelas referências, mas a resposta do bigown explica mais claramente que a documentação.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O primeiro lê **um** caractere do *buffer* e o segundo lê uma linha, ou seja, todos os caracteres até que encontre um indicador de fim de linha.

Por ler apenas um caractere o `Read()` retorna um inteiro indicando qual seria o caractere lido. Ele sequer é um `char`. É necessário uma conversão se precisar da informação como caractere mesmo. E obviamente se precisar como *string* a conversão também é necessária. O `ReadLine()` retorna uma *string* para acomodar toda a linha. O sinal de fim de linha não faz parte desta *string* resultante.

Este *buffer* normalmente é o teclado. Não há garantias que venha de lá mas a entrada padrão usada pelo console é este dispositivo. Obviamente ele pode ter sido redirecionado mas o C# ou o .NET não precisa saber disto. Por isto, normalmente o indicador de fim de linha é gerado quando o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> é acionado. Tecnicamente falando é quando recebe uma *string* [`NewLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Environment_NewLine).

Código fonte do [`Read()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,065d23785fb8ba35,references) ([.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/IO/StdInReader.cs,256)) e do [`ReadLine()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,91b2c7adbdc4b165) ([.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/IO/StdInReader.cs,8da02db3bea865f2)). Precisa fuçar em outras partes do código para entender tudo, mas é um começo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então se eu tentar ler algo com read em uma variável do tipo string gerará um erro?

Comment: Sim, eu editei para informar isto.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi agora.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, você vai querer utilizar o **Console.Read()** quando você quiser que retorne o **VALOR ASCII** do primeiro caractere digitado.

Caso você queira apenas um caractere terá de fazer algumas verificações, pois nenhum valor retornará assim.

Sendo então:

- Console.ReadKey() **Retorna o valor da tecla pressionada**
- Console.ReadLine() **Retorna o valor da linha inteira**
- Console.Read() **Retorna o valor em ASCII do primeiro caractere digitado na linha**

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de entender isso na prática onde uma  variável do meu  código (int) receberia via teclado, por exemplo: 240 e posteriormente fazia uma multiplicação dessa variável com outra, mas o resultado final da multiplicação sempre dava errado. Testando a saída da variável ela exibia 50 ao invés de 240.

Culpa do Read(); Solução dada por uma amigo aqui do stack

`variável = Convert.Toint32(Console.Readline());`

Comment: De maneira geral isto não é adequado.

Comment: @Maniero , pq? Poderia falar mais a respeito?

Comment: Já respondi inúmeras vezes sobre isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+tryparse