# Leitura de inteiro via console

Tags: c#, variáveis, inteiros

Boa noite, pessoal. Uma pergunta básica:

No código abaixo

```
    class Conversora
    {
        double Oneknot = 1.852; // km/h


    public void Conversor(){

        Console.WriteLine("Informe a velocidade em nós: " );
        int speed = Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("A velocidade em km/h é de: " + Oneknot * speed);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

A leitura da variável speed não sai conforme o que foi digitado. Exemplo: se eu digito 240 nós, a variável recebe apenas 50. Logo a conversão de nós para km/h sai com resultado errado.

Alguém dá um help pro noob aqui ? rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia. Para simplificar apenas use Console.ReadLine(); pois o Read() lê apenas um caractere, um buffer, e o ReadLine() lê toda linha até encontrar um indicador que chegou ao final da linha. Atítulo de comparação faça a conta com uma calculadora. veja mais nessa referência:

[Diferença entre Console.Read(); e Console.ReadLine();](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50950/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-console-read-e-console-readline)

```
 class Conversora
{
    double Oneknot = 1.852; // km/h


    public void Conversor()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Informe a velocidade em nós: ");
        int speed = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("A velocidade em km/h é de: " + Oneknot * speed);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente agora. :)

Answer (score 5):

O que acontece é que o `Console.Read` lê somente um caractere e o converte para decimal de acordo com a tabela ascii, no seu caso, lendo o 2 e convertendo para 50. Ao invés disso, use o `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
class Conversora
{
    double Oneknot = 1.852; // km/h

    public void Conversor()
    {
        int speed;
        do{
            Console.WriteLine("Informe a velocidade em nós: " );
        }
        while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out speed));
        Console.WriteLine("A velocidade em km/h é de: " + Oneknot * speed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Use o `int.TryParse` para verificar se o usuário está colocando dados válidos para um número inteiro.

Comment: Acho que faltou o `!`

Comment: @LINQ Eu tava no smartphone haha, não testei. Já editei, obrigado! =)

Comment: Funcionou @Francisco. Valeu pelo toque com o int.TryParse ;)