# Entrada do console não é tratada corretamente

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows, visual-studio-2019

Ao compilar meu código no Visual Studio Professional 2019, ele está dando erro, por exemplo:

```
Digite sua idade : 12
Você é adulto
```

Código:

```
using System; //Usa A Biblioteca System

public class Idade 
{
    public static void Main() //Inicia a função principal Main
    {

        Console.WriteLine("qual sua idade? "); //Mostra um Texto na tela
        Int32 n1 = Console.Read(); 
        Convert.ToInt32(n1);
        Int32 n2 = n1;
        if (n2 < 10)  {
            Console.WriteLine("Você é Criança");

        }
        if (n2 > 10 && n2 < 18 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Você é Adolescente");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Você é Adulto");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um problema que é quase sintaxe (não está guardando em lugar algum o valor convertido), e outro que está lendo uma tecla e não um dado, leia a documentação antes de usar qualquer no seu código. Sem fazer isso sempre programará errado. Não pode usar algo sem entender todos os detalhes dele. Veja [Diferença entre Console.Read(); e Console.ReadLine();](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50950/101).

E ainda criou uma variável que faz nada.

O `if` está desperdiçando recursos porque ele fica separado em dois independentes então o segundo será executado mesmo que entre no primeiro e não precisa disto, aí a comparação pode ser simplificada porque se ele não entrou no segundo já é certo que uma parte da condição desse `if` já é verdadeiro.

E no seu código se a pessoa tiver 10 anos ela é é um adulto, então isso é um erro também.

Só por curiosidade, a legislação estabelece que uma pessoa é adolescente com 12 anos e não 10.

E ainda tem outro problema que quase todo mundo erra porque a digitação pode falhar e isto acontecendo seu código quebra, mas não é um erro claro porque na maioria das vezes funcionará. Eu preferi sair do código quando algo deu errado, mas pode mandar fazer o que quiser. veja [Diferenças entre Parse vs TryParse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) e [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101).

Também modernizei o código e tirei os comentários porque eles são obviedades, esse tipo de comentário só atrapalha, nesse caso específico não serve nem de forma didática, até pela inconsistência.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Idade {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Qual sua idade? ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n1)) return; 
        else if (n1 < 10) WriteLine("Você é Criança");
        else if (n1 < 18) WriteLine("Você é Adolescente");
        else WriteLine("Você é Adulto");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UcSIZw). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CPG6hd). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Aging.cs).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação cara eu tava realmente fazendo sem ler direito a documentação ! muito obrigado!